# redefining Console colour palette in c#

Tags: c#

Could somebody please tell me how can I redefine the colour palette of the Console in C#?

Answer (score 10):

Yeah, it's possible.  You'll need a bunch of P/Invoke declarations to use code like this:

```
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX info;
info.cbSize = sizeof(info);
HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(hConsole, &info);
info.ColorTable[14] = RGB(255, 128, 0);  // Replace yellow
SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(hConsole, &info);
SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUNDINTENSITY | FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN);
```

Visit pinvoke.net or use the P/Invoke Interop Assistant to get the declarations you need to use this code.

Comment: I think your code will just let you use the standard colors, which you don't need to P/Invoke to do -- that's already available on the Console class. The question (as I read it) was, can you use colors other than the predefined 16?

Comment: @Joe: note how this code sets an entry in the ColorTable array.  That's what replaces the default color, yellow in this case.  The ColorTable has 16 entries, initially the 16 default colors as configured by Windows and/or the program's shortcut.

Comment: I deleted my answer, I didn't know about this.