# True color support inside a console using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, colors, console-application

When working with a Console application, one can't help but to notice that the native commands BackgroundColor and ForegroundColor only support CGA color spectrum (Yellow, Red, Dark Yellow, Dark Red, etc)

[image]

What I would like to do is to expand on this so that I can use ANY color that is supported by my current resolution (aka, True Color, etc), and not just this limited color pool.

When writing a DOS application (yes. DOS --- ancient old-school DOS), I had no problems selecting pretty much ANY color going well beyond this limitation. I recall seeing something regarding how to do this in the infant years of .NET (year 2002), but I cannot locate it as every link regarding "console" and "color" in searches come up with how to color, and only in the absolute most basic colors as depicted in the image --- essentially showing people how to change the ForegroundColor and BackgroundColor properties.

TO CLARIFY - I Want to be able to use TRUE COLOR aka, the entire color spectrum available for the Font Color, and Background Color inside a Console application using VB.NET.

I found an article on here showing how to find the "closest" console color to any given color, but that won't work. The basic colors are missing many real colors such as Orange -- and well, at minimum 1000 other named colors.

I am OK with hacking the crap outta this via use of the Win32/etc API's, and logic deems this must be possible due to the vast number of applications that run inside the console allowing for true color or at least VGA support.

Comment: Actually, I do not think this is possible. I think the Win32 Console only supports those 16 colors. You say that "logic deems this must be possible due to the vast number of applications that run inside the console allowing for true color or at least VGA support", but I haven't seen any examples of that. Every app that I know of that can do this uses an alternative, third-party console tool, something like [Console2](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Console2ABetterWindowsCommandPrompt.aspx) or the many others. What have you seen that uses the *Windows* Console and displays more than 16 colors?

Comment: Run windows 98... open up Doom in Console.   Same with Windows XP, etc where DOSshell is now embedded terminal.  I'm sure that is enough of an example --- if not ... Carmen Sandiago -- or even better .. .GifViewer, etc etc etc.  All of which render more than these base colors in Console.   Additionally, I don't see any evidence in "Console2"'s documentation about extending these colors.  Lastly, I did this in VB6 --  which doesn't even support Console except through some slick core API code, and a hack on the final exec to convert from GUI.

Comment: If you did it in VB 6, then it should be fairly straightforward to convert the code to VB.NET. Perhaps you can post the VB 6 code?

Comment: @Code Gray - Yes and no.  It was an API only method which many API's that are declared as type any, are not supported in .NET. Additionally, API only console I would lose the threaded approach the native .net one provides

Comment: VB.NET doesn't support "As Any", but you can overload the signatures, which is effectively the same. "As Any" isn't magic. These are C APIs that you're invoking, and the only "Any" in C is a void pointer. *Anything* that is callable from C or VB 6 is callable using P/Invoke. And I don't know what you mean about losing the threaded approach. The .NET Framework doesn't provide its own console. The BCL just wraps the Win32 console functions up in a nice object-oriented package. The entire operating system supports threading, it was just a PITA from VB 6. Those days are over, thankfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out my original comment was a bit premature. I was only half-right. It isn't that the console window only supports *those* 16 colors (i.e., the standard VGA palette). It does support *other* colors, but **it only supports 16 colors at a time**. You can change the colors in the palette to anything you want, but there is a maximum of 16.

You can see the color palette by right-clicking on a console window, going to Properties, and flipping to the "Colors" tab. Select a color from the row of colors and you can customize it to any RGB value that you want. You can do this while running an application that uses those colors to see the effect.

The `SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx` function provides a programmatic API to set these colors as well, but it is only supported on Windows Vista and later. You can P/Invoke it from a .NET application. It looks like there is some [sample code on pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx). Do take care copying and pasting declarations directly from that site—I've found lots of errors, and so have many other Stack Overflow users, judging from the questions I've seen about it. You'll also find information about this technique in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219548/redefining-console-colour-palette-in-c-sharp). It should be trivial to translate the C# code to VB.NET.

If you need to support older operating systems (and who doesn't?), you'll have to resort to undocumented APIs. This is normally risky, because your code is likely to break when the OS is updated, but it's not such a big deal when you're only using it with those operating systems for which no new updates are forthcoming. Searching the web, I see some sample code [here](http://www.catch22.net/sites/default/source/files/setconsoleinfo.c). There are no credits given in the file, so I guess it was written by James Brown, the owner of [Catch22.net](http://www.catch22.net/about). I assume it is in the public domain, but I have no evidence to support that. If you're handy with WinDbg, you can probably reverse engineer it for yourself.

Both of these approaches will do the same thing. You will effectively remap the standard 16 colors to any color of your choosing, allowing you to display more vivid images. For example, you might decide that no one needs a "dark yellow", so you might replace it with orange. You could even reset the color palette *continually* to create special effects.

The games you described might be an exception. Old-school game programmers often subverted the operating system and communicated directly with the video driver in an attempt to eke out additional performance. Back in those days, it used to be necessary. A consequence of doing so is that they were able to access some additional modes that were not directly exposed by the operating system, like [mode 13h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_13h). This had a fixed resolution of 320x200 pixels, but it had two main benefits: (1) it allowed simple, direct access to the video memory, and (2) it allowed the use of the fixed VGA 256-color palette.

I know you can do this from DOS, but I'm not sure if you can do it from NT DOS. Perhaps you can, since you say that the games run on Windows XP. Even if you can, you're going to have a hard time getting going. Modern compilers don't include any of the libraries that allow you to interact directly with the video hardware. You'll probably want to get your hands on a vintage compiler like Turbo C just to see how it's done. The `graphics.h` header had a nice interface for all of this stuff.

Truth be told, all of that was really before my time, but I believe you essentially called an interrupt, like so

```
mov  al, 13h
mov  ah, 0h
int  10h
```

I'm betting that NT's console will fight you tooth and nail on this, though.

A slightly better workaround might be to obtain the console's graphics buffer directly. I've never tried it myself, but [this site](http://blog.airesoft.co.uk/2012/10/things-ms-can-do-that-they-dont-tell-you-about-console-graphics/) suggests that it is possible, albeit also undocumented. It also notes that it only works on 32-bit Windows because its only purpose is to drive the 16-bit emulator that lets you play those old DOS games in mode 13h.

Comment: Looking through this now.  Hacking the pallette isn't a bad workaround, I'm just curious on it's effects  (also confusing)

Answer (score 6):

The console was only ever meant to provide a way to port text mode programs from older operating system versions.  Your memory of what was possible is perhaps too hazy after all these years.  MS-Dos never provided a way to directly set colors beyond the ANSI.SYS device driver, you had to send escape codes to alter text colors.  Largely ignored, more common was to use the BIOS, [interrupt 10h](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/labmanual/graphics-int10h.html), function 9.  The BL register specifies the attribute, 4 bits for the foreground color and 4 bits for the background color.  The choice of colors was hardwired in the video adapter and monitor.

But by far the most common approach was to write directly into the video frame buffer, address 0xB800:0.  Every cell on the screen was mapped by two bytes, 1 for the character and 1 for the attribute.  Primarily necessary to do something about the horrible blinking that early video adapters suffered from when they scrolled the screen.  CGA was not exactly a triumph of IBM engineering.  Hercules was a company that made a [very popular alternative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hercules_Graphics_Card), it practically set its own standard.

PC gaming got its boost from the VGA adapter, like Doom.  The successor of the CGA and EGA adapter, it supported 256 color graphics modes.  It required a different monitor, an analog one, and had a programmable DAC (Digital to Analog Converter) with 256 registers to select 256 colors from the possible 16 million.  That introduced the world to the notion of a *palette*, quite a painful programming challenge.  I very unfondly remember battling the [RealizePalette()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162896%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) winapi function.

Windows was also the primary boost for true color 24bpp video adapters, breaking through the confines of the BIOS modes.  Around 1994 they started to become affordable.  That support was never back-ported to the BIOS, it stayed stuck in the 1980s.

What you remember from Windows 9x was not a console.  Olden 16-bit DOS programs ran in an emulator.  They continued to ab/use the video frame buffer, writing to 0xB800:0 for text mode and 0xA000:0 for graphics mode and twiddle the video adapter control registers directly.  Primary support for intercepting that direct hardware access was provided by the processor, it ran in "virtual 8086" mode.  An important sub-component for that emulator was the "video grabber", a driver that could map the virtualized video adapter memory to pixels in a window.  It is that window that you remember seeing.  Notable was the Alt+Enter key press, it could turn off the video grabber on-the-fly, switching back-and-forth between full screen and windowed view.

Long story short, the console window only ever attempted to emulate the BIOS text video modes.  All that was needed.  With its fixed interpretation of the "attribute", 4 bits to pick 1 of 16 colors for the foreground and 4 bits for the background.  Programs that use the graphics video modes must run full-screen.  Few still work, the 64-bit version of Windows is no longer capable of switching the processor into virtual 8086 mode, support for it was dropped by AMD/Intel.

There are some extensions to the BIOS text mode, the window isn't stuck to a fixed width and height and supports scrolling.  And the notion of a palette is supported in a console window.  You don't have to settle for the garish legacy colors, you can directly change them from the system menu.  Properties menu item, Colors tab.  Programmatically done with SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(), [CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX.ColorTable member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682091%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  An array of 16 RGB values.  Otherwise another strong reminder that 16 is a rock-hard limit :)  And the attribute was extended from 8-bits to 16-bits, providing [7 extra bits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682013%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for special effects.  Very rarely ever used, apis that wrap the winapi console functions tend to be based on the legacy BIOS capabilities as well.

Comment: This is good information, and I appreciate the refresher.  I understand why the limitations were initially there, however I am at a loss as to why they are still there. It also seems that some things which were light-years simpler using ASM or even QBasic (like setting the full background color, not just on a char by char basis: was SET BACKCOLOR=####  or something to that effect) worked in Batch files did not require FS to work. Using this info (and Cody), I could create a virtual palette that breaks down at least 256 into 16 bit blocks and swap as needed based on the size of the color value.

Answer (score 1):

**Self-promotion here:**

https://github.com/aybe/TrueColorConsole

24-bit coloring and VT features for .NET System.Console !

- 95% of the features have been implemented
- to output 24-bit it takes nothing more than a `VTConsole.WriteLine(string, Color)`

(until MSFT decides to add it directly to the framework)

Comment: This looks good, and shows once more, that just because something hasn't been done, doesn't mean it can't be done.  Will play around with this later.

Comment: Thanks, enjoy it and feel free to improve it 