# How to programmatically change the popup colors for the current instance of a windows console?

Tags: c#, .net

In .NET, I can use the `Console` class to change the color index (effectively 0-15) for the foreground and background colors of the console via `Console.BackGroundColor` and `Console.ForegroundColor` respectively. Both of these properties then use the Win32 `SetConsoleTextAttribute` function to affect the change.

I can also use the `ScreenColors` and `PopupColors` keys in the registry, beneath `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` to change the background and foreground indexes for both the normal and popup foreground and background colors for the default console properties.

What I can't find is any means of changing the popup color indexes for the current console, either in the `Console` .NET class, nor in the Win32 console APIs.

Does such an API exist, and if so, which one is it?

Comment: If you have Windows 10 TH2 or later you can just use standard ANSI escape codes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842424/list-of-ansi-color-escape-sequences

Comment: Actually reading your question more carefully, not sure if that will work for popup colors

Comment: Possible undocumented Win API http://www.catch22.net/sites/default/source/files/setconsoleinfo.c

Comment: Google "c# setconsolescreenbufferinfoex" for hits.  [This is one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3219873/17034).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, all. It had indeed been staring me in the face re `SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx()` and I'd completely missed it.